# Why I cannot run the SQL Server 2019 setup.exe file?

Tags: sql, installation, sql-server-2019, setup.exe

I have been encountering all sort of problems to istall the SQL Server 2019 Express as well as SSMS v. 18.9. I wanted to move from SSQLSERVER 2014 and SSMS 2014 to 2019 version in order to attend a course on T-SQL using the latest version of the software.

After unstalling 2014 Server and Management studio files, I have been unable to install the 2019 version, either the Basic installation (the error says that **"there has been an error when checking the installation rules for SQL Server"**), or by downloading the resources (in this case, when I click on the setup.exe file a error dialog window appears with a red X saying **"SQL Server setup"**).

Any tips, please?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Setup.exe error image]

[image: SQL Server Installer error at the end of basic installation]

Comment: Are you running a supported operating system? Sounds like the system you are using doesn't meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: Please [edit[ your question and supply more info regarding these errors. Can you paste in the error message, or at the very least a screenshot